# Cross Compiling Go

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, go, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile Go for ubuntu linux x86_64 on my macbook. I have followed instructions outlined [here](http://dave.cheney.net/2012/09/08/an-introduction-to-cross-compilation-with-go) but when I run `go-linux-amd64 build` I get the following message `go build runtime: linux/amd64 must be bootstrapped using make.bash`. Any help with this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 31):

What it's saying you need to do is rebuild the library and runtime for linux-amd64. You can do that this way:

1. Find the root of your Go installation (if you don't know where this is, running `which go` may help - the binary is often installed with the rest of the sources).
2. `cd` into the `src` directory
3. Run `GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 ./make.bash --no-clean` (or `GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 bash make.bash --no-clean` if `make.bash` is not executable). This will rebuild the library and runtime using the specified OS and architecture.

Once you've done this, you can build a go package or binary for this architecture using `GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build`. You can follow the same instructions for other architectures and operating systems.

### Edit (08/13/15):

As of Go 1.5, cross compiling is *much* easier. Since the runtime is written in Go, there's no need to set anything up in order to be able to cross-compile. You can now just run `GOOS=<os> GOARCH=<arch> go build` from a vanilla Go installation and it will work.

However, there's one exception to this. If you're using cgo, you'll still need to set stuff up ahead of time. And you'll need to inform the tooling that you want to enable cgo cross-compiling by setting the `CGO_ENABLED` environment variable to `1`. So, to be precise:

1. `cd` into the `src` directory of your Go installation (see the instructions above).
2. Run `CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=<os> GOARCH=<arch> ./make.bash --no-clean`
3. Run `CGO_ENABLED=1 go build` to build your project. It is important that you specify `CGO_ENABLED=1` even when you're compiling.

Comment: Oh I forgot! You have to also add the `--no-clean` flag to `make.bash` or else it might overwrite your old installation (if this happens, no worries - just rerun `make.bash` for your old configuration as well, this time with the `--no-clean` flag).

Comment: Instead of `which go`, I'd recommend `go env GOROOT` (or just `go env` to show everything, but GOROOT is the one you want). Even if you haven't set a GOROOT environment variable (and it's recommended you don't) this will show you where go expects to find it's tools and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Following the above answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27413148/3675575, I needed to set `GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP` to recompile my GO source tree:

```
GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=/usr/lib/golang/ CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=linux GOARCH=386 ./make.bash --no-clean
```

(I'm using Fedora 23, so the GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP may vary in your operating system)

Answer (score -1):

You must `cd %goroot%/src/,find make.bash`

Then execute `./make.bash`

execute your command.  Try it!